# Handling Overflow in Fixed Point arithmetic

Tags: algorithm, c++11, fixed-point

I am implementing fixed point arithmetic using the slides [1]. Everything is working as it should my question is the slides linked, also every resource I read says when multiplying and dividing fixed point numbers there is a good change they overflow. So they suggest casting them to a bigger size to multiply then cast back. Like,

```
(INT32)(((INT64)a *
        (INT64)b) >> N)
```

instead of just,

```
 ((a * b) >> N)
```

This works for 8,16,32 bit integers but how do I handle overflow for 64 bit integer? There is no 128 bit int type (AFAIK gcc has 128 bit integers but they are not portable.)

I also would like to via the constructor auto calculate required bits for the user supplied epsilon (minimum required fraction accuracy) Like so,

If 0.01 accuracy is required 6 bits is enough for N. (Since 1/64 = 0.015) I couldn't figure out the logic for converting accuracy to required bits?

[1] http://jet.ro/files/The_neglected_art_of_Fixed_Point_arithmetic_20060913.pdf

Comment: To convert accuracy to required bits you can use a simple math formula. `floor(log(1.0/required_accuracy)/log(2))`

Comment: Implement [long multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication). Recall how, in elementary school, you could multiply two-digit decimal numbers using only single-digit multiplication table.

Comment: Long multiplication, as Igor says... but 64-bit fixed-point is not very useful so you probably don't need to bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

well you can chain 64 bit ops to produce N*64 bit operations. With `+,-` it is simple `O(n)` stacking. For `*,^2` you can use Karatsuba for more info see related **QA**s:

- [Fast bignum square computation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214)
- [Cant make value propagate through carry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214)
- [Building a logarithm function in C without using float type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214)

Also Division is possible using dividers like this (or any other approximation):

- [Floating Point Divider Hardware Implementation Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398246/2521214)

For more info you can look at source code of any bigint/bigdecimal lib out there.

Another way to deal with overflow/underflow is this:

- [How to deal with overflow and underflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33006665/2521214)