# Excel ROUND function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, algorithm, math, rounding

I've got a mathematical formula in Excel, which is the following:

```
ROUND((B2+C2)*(B55/100)/12;2)
```

Initial values:

- B2 = 1000
- C2 = 0
- B55 = 0,03

Results (t means time in months).
[image: Values from excel]

Here is my Javascript approach:

```js
(function _calculateRates() {
  var singlePayment = parseInt(1000, 10),
    amount = singlePayment,
    monthlyPayment = parseInt(0, 10),
    investTime = parseFloat(12),
    rate_a = parseFloat(0.03),
    rate_b = parseFloat(0.03),
    investment = monthlyPayment,
    interest = 0;

  for (var month = 0; month < investTime; month += 1) {
    investment = (month === 0) ? 0 : monthlyPayment;

    interest = Number(((amount + investment) * (rate_a / 100) / 12).toFixed(2));
    amount = Number((amount + interest + investment).toFixed(2));
  }
  console.log('Result: ', amount);
})();
```

As one can see, the result is not correct.

Where can I find the Microsoft Excel algorithm for ROUND() ?

Comment: What is the result that gets logged, and what result do you want instead?

Comment: give a single value example please

Comment: In excel, is the argument separator the comma (,) or the semi-colon (;) ? what is excel showing as the result? It should come out as 2dp...

Comment: rounding to 2 decimals ... `floor((100.0*x)+0.5)*0.01;` for different number of places you just change the `100` and `0.01` for `10^n` and `10^-n`

Comment: In `Excel` `=0.3/12` evaluates to `0.025`. So rounded to 2 decimals is `0.03`. In `JavaScript` `var result = 0.3/12;` results in `0.024999999999999998`. That `.toFixed(2)` is `0.02`. That's why the difference.

Comment: @AxelRichter 12 / 3 is 4 and 3 / 12 is 0.25, so why does javascript have such an issue?

Comment: @Solar Mike: Not only `JavaScript` but all systems using [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) will have that "issue". `Excel` additional has accuracy of only 15 digits maximum. This looks like an advantage here but sometimes it is not.

Comment: @AxelRichter so that result is not "precision" it is "error"...

Comment: @Solar Mike: That's correct. All electronic systems we are using currently are **not** able doing floating point arithmetic in 100% accuracy. But this is as it is. We have to live with it.

Comment: @SolarMike the problem is 0.3 can not be represented inbinary as exact binary number ... its irrational in there  so the value is slightly less then `0.3` leading to slight less than  `0.025` result which get round down so its rounding error based... to remedy you can try this [How to deal with overflow and underflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33006665/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre: I posted my answer in the hope someone would counter having a better `JavaScript` rounding approach than `Math.floor((Math.pow(10, n) * x ) + 0.5) * Math.pow(10, -n)`. This is really unwieldly, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel `=0.3/12` evaluates to `0.025`. So rounded to 2 decimals it is `0.03`.

In JavaScript `var result = 0.3/12;` results in `0.024999999999999998`. That `.toFixed(2)` is `0.02`.

Internally `Excel` also gets `0.024999999999999998` like all systems using [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). But it has the additional rule, to only take 15 digits maximum. That is `0.02499999999999` + `0.000000000000009`, which is `0.025`.

So we cannot using `.toFixed` in `JavaScript`. If we are using another method for rounding in `JavaScript` the this leads to the same result as in `Excel`.

See example using simple values:

```js
var result = 0.3/12;
console.log(result);
console.log(result.toFixed(2));
console.log(Math.floor((Math.pow(10, 2)*result)+0.5)*Math.pow(10, -2));
```

See example using your algorithm:

```js
(function _calculateRates() {
  var singlePayment = parseInt(1000, 10),
    amount = singlePayment,
    monthlyPayment = parseInt(0, 10),
    investTime = parseFloat(12),
    rate_a = parseFloat(0.03),
    rate_b = parseFloat(0.03),
    investment = monthlyPayment,
    interest = 0;

  for (var month = 0; month < investTime; month += 1) {
    investment = (month === 0) ? 0 : monthlyPayment;

    interest = Number(((amount + investment) * (rate_a / 100) / 12));
    interest = Math.floor((Math.pow(10, 2)*interest)+0.5)*Math.pow(10, -2);
    amount = Number((amount + interest + investment));
    amount = Math.floor((Math.pow(10, 2)*amount)+0.5)*Math.pow(10, -2);
  }
  console.log('Result: ', amount);
})();
```

Because it is related to this question, especially why in `JavaScript` `var result = 0.3/12;` results in `0.024999999999999998`, the link to [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/) could be helpful.